# Email setup problem

Tags: emails

I'm new at using Craft. A friend had some problem with her website and I'm trying to help as much as I can.

Unfortunately, I have a problem with email sending.

The domain is on a server and email exchange is on another server.

At the moment, the current protocol is PHP Mail. I tried to change to SMTP. I've talked with hosting for email, and they said that they don't provide this service, and that I need to setup my own SMTP server. How do I do that? :)

Also, if you have any tips/tricks on how to make the email sending work, I truly appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What's the issue you are having with sending mail from Craft using PHP Mail? You really don't want to set up your own smtp server if you can avoid it. Here's some [guidelines on troubleshooting email errors in Craft](https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors) on the support pages.

Comment: I've checked the link you provided and in craft.log this is the message I get:

`[error] [exception.Craft\EmailTestException] Craft\Exception: Email error: Could not instantiate mail function. in /home/username/data/app/services/EmailService.php:472`

and

`Next Craft\EmailTestException: Email settings test failure in /home/username/data/app/controllers/SystemSettingsController.php:199`